# How to fetch sms using static method

Tags: java, android, sms, non-static

SmsAdapter.java

```
package com.s4starb4boy.smstopdf.adapter;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.s4starb4boy.smstopdf.R;
    import com.s4starb4boy.smstopdf.model.SMS;

    import java.util.List;



    public class SmsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SmsAdapter.SmsViewHolder> {


        private static final String TAG = SmsAdapter.class.getSimpleName() ;
        private List<SMS> smsList;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public SmsAdapter(Context context, List<SMS> smsList) {
            this.smsList = smsList;
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public SmsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            Log.i(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_list, parent, false);
            SmsViewHolder holder = new SmsViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(SmsViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder" + position);
            SMS currentObj = smsList.get(position);
            holder.setData(currentObj, position);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return smsList.size();
        }

        class SmsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            TextView tvPhoneNo;
            TextView tvsmsBody;
            int position;
            SMS current;

            public SmsViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tvPhoneNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNo);
                tvsmsBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessageBody);
            }

            public void setData(SMS current, int position) {
                this.tvPhoneNo.setText(current.getPhoneNo());
                this.tvsmsBody.setText(current.getSmsBody());
                this.current =current;
                this.position = position;
            }
        }
    }
```

SMS.java

```
public class SMS extends AppCompatActivity{
    private String phoneNo;
    private String smsBody;

    public SMS(String phoneNo, String smsBody) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
        this.smsBody = smsBody;
    }

    public SMS() {
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public String getSmsBody() {
        return smsBody;
    }

    public void setSmsBody(String smsBody) {
        this.smsBody = smsBody;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getSMS(){
        ArrayList<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
            String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
            String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);
        }

        if (cur != null) {
            cur.close();
        }
        return sms;
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    private static final int READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1;



    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUpToolbar();
        setUpRecyclerView();

    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        SmsAdapter adapter = new SmsAdapter(this, SMS.getSMS());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManagerVertical = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLinearLayoutManagerVertical.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManagerVertical);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    }

    private void setUpToolbar() {

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Navigation Drawer Demo");
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                String msg = "";
                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.settings:

                        msg = "Settings";
                        break;

                    case R.id.edit:
                        msg = "Edit";
                        break;

                    case R.id.search:
                        msg = "Search";
                        break;

                    case R.id.exit:
                        msg = "Exit";
                        break;

                    case R.id.delete:
                        msg = "Delete";
                        break;

                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
            }

        });

        }
}
```

Above are all code I want to fetch sms and display them in card view using recycler view. I am repeating here that I am absolutely beginner so please keep this point in your mind while giving me solution I may unable to get your professional hint rather ask me in detail plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass current `context` object to the `SMS` class

```
SmsAdapter adapter = new SmsAdapter(this, SMS.getSMS(this.getApplicationContext()));
```

and change `getSMS` to:

```
 public static ArrayList<String> getSMS(Context context){
   .....
   Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
   .....
```

Unfortunately I don't have any Android IDE to test this but it should work.

Comment: only getSMS error removed now when I call it in MainActivity by passing Conetx of that activity it again shows error if you have IDE then try and see yourself I am unable to explain it here as I am novice.

Answer (score 0):

> getContentResolver>>>nonstatic member can not be referenced

This means, you are trying to access non-static member from static context, in case `getContentResolver()` is non-static method, which you are trying to invoke from static method i.e. `getSMS ()`

You can do either :

1. Remove `static` from `getSMS` **OR** add `static` to `getContentResolver`
2. Create an instance of this class to call `getContentResolver`

Comment: private void setUpRecyclerView() {


        SMS sms = new SMS();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        SmsAdapter adapter = new SmsAdapter(this,  sms.getSMS());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManagerVertical = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLinearLayoutManagerVertical.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManagerVertical);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    }

Comment: @s4starb4boy what is this ?? You need to tell, don't simply paste the code. Did you tried my post ?

Comment: yes I tried, sorry sir I am new bie I paste it to show this is where I am calling that method which is in SMS class I am still getting the same error.when I remove static then I cant call it..may I post whole code here if you want.

Comment: Its still not working! Thanks you all for help and showing concern to fix this issue I'll try from scratch.

Comment: @s4starb4boy what is not working ?? I hope you got the answer now, as you have accepted other answer

Comment: Thanks Ravi! One error got fix then new error arises. What I want is simply fetch the sms inbox via class and display them in cardview using recyclerview and custom adapter but I am unable to achieve it. I want getSMS method as static which should return ArrayList of fetched sms now I tried best but could not get the result so I decided to start it from scratch with different approach or logic. Thanks again for your help.